# SQLAlchemy unproper data updating

Tags: python, sqlite, google-app-engine, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I`m writing a simple web application on **Flask + SQLALchemy + sqllite**

I have such class:

```
class Document(db.Model):
    # Sha will be primary key for every document
    hex_sha = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, primary_key = True)
    # How many times this document was uploaded
    count = db.Column(db.Integer)
    def __init__(self, hex_sha):
        self.hex_sha = hex_sha
        self.count = 1
```

From the client side, you can upload some txt file, and the server must return,how many times file with such **SHA256 hash** value was uploaded.

Firstly I convert file to utf-8 representation, and then find SHA256 from it, using **hashlib** library:

```
from hashlib import sha256
file_hex_sha = sha256()
file_hex_sha.update(file)
file_hex_sha = file_hex_sha.hexdigest()
```

Then I check,if such SHA256 hash already stored in my database.If it is,I increment counter by one, otherwise I create new record with such SHA256 hash:

```
# Try to find such document in db
db_file = Document.query.filter_by(hex_sha=file_hex_sha).first()
# If there is no such document in database
if db_file is None:
    new_db_file = Document(file_hex_sha)
    db.session.add(new_db_file)
    response = str(new_db_file.count)
    db.session.commit()
    return response
# If we found same document
else:
    db_file.count += 1
    response = str(db_file.count)
    db.session.commit()
    return response
```

When I test this code on localhost, it works properly.

But when I deployed this app on Google App Engine, I`ve got such issue:

When I upload the same file many times, the counter return something like this

```
Amount is:
1
2
3
4
1 <-----
2 <-----
5
3
...
```

So it seems, that SQLAlchemy create new record,despite such record already exist (and sha key is **primary and unqique**)

Where could I make a mistake?

Comment: I'd remove `self.count = 1` and change column declaration to `count = db.Column(db.Integer, default=1)` just to check. P.S. Actually, I don't like that __init__ at all, I feel that it might be a problem. If I were you, I'd rewrite model to utilize 'default' kwarg and delete __init__ .

Comment: I have tried the tip you said, but it didn`t help

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because the requests are being processed in **parallel**. This results in a **race condition** and thus the count is being over-written.

The solution for the following MySql construct: `SELECT <Query> FOR UPDATE`

This does a **row lock**.

This can be achieved in sqlalchemy via `with_for_update`

You can read more on this here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.Select.with_for_update